# Toggle "scanning always available" programmatically

Tags: android, wifi, settings

Starting with Android 4.3, there is an option under WiFi advanced settings page for "scanning always available". This ultimately means that WiFi is always on even if the user thinks they have disabled it (see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860890/how-does-androids-scan-only-mode-work)).

Is there a way to toggle this setting programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows a dialog. It's up to the user to allow the setting.

```
private static final int REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE = some_number;

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && !wifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable()) {
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE, REQUEST_SCAN_ALWAYS_AVAILABLE));
}
```

Comment: This only shows how to enable it. The OP asked about toggling the setting.

Comment: @davis that's not possible and this is the next best thing

Comment: Aware of using it. Guaranteed crash on Meizu devices with `ActivityNotFoundException`. Chinese coders should be slapped really hard for that